# python generators: yield and yield from

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def foo(word, i):
    if i >= len(word):
        return

    yield from foo(word, i+1)
    yield word[i]

for j in foo("intro", 0): print(j, end = "")
```

The code prints `ortni`. the compiler debugger is unable to help and i'm not sure how it works. I tried to read on `yield from` and `yield` but I don't understand how it works in this example.

How the above code prints "ortni" (the character in backward)? how does it work?

Comment: `yield from x` is equivalent to `for item in x: yield item` - does that help?

Comment: Essentially, what the function does is: to print `intro` backwards, first print `ntro` backwards then print `i`. To print `ntro` backwards, first print `tro` backwards, then print `n`. etc...

Answer (score 6):

Each call to `foo` creates an iterator that

1. Yields all the values produced by a recursive call
2. A value indicated by word[i]

```
Value of i           Number of values yielded
    len(word)                 0
    len(word) - 1             1
    len(word) - 2             2
       ...                    ...
         i                 len(word) -i
       ...                    ...
       0                   len(word)
```

Because the recursive call is made first, values are yielded in the reverse order that they are retrieved using `word.__getitem__`.

```
foo("intro", 0)
yield from foo("intro", 1)
           yield from foo("intro", 2)
                      yield from foo("intro", 3)
                                 yield from foo("intro", 4)
                                            yield from foo("intro", 5)
                                                       return
                                            yield "intro"[4]  # "o"
                                 yield "intro"[3]  # "r"
                      yield "intro"[2]  # "t"
           yield "intro"[1]  # "n"
yield "intro"[0]  # "i"
```